# How to include Swagger API key in header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I am using `Swagger API`. It is giving me desired output. But, while testing, I changed the API key to some wrong API key (expecting it to give error), but it still gave me correct output (which I was getting with correct API key). Why is this happening?

Following is the code I have in `SwaggerConfig.cs`:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using WebActivatorEx;
using CalendarDetails;
using Swashbuckle.Application;
using System;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Web.Configuration;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace CalendarDetails
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                 .EnableSwagger(c =>
                    {
                        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "CalendarDetails");

                        c.ApiKey(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiKey"])
                            .Description("API Key Authentication")
                            .Name("X-ApiKey")
                            .In("header");
                        c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());

                    })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                    {
                        c.EnableApiKeySupport("X-ApiKey", "header");
                    });
        }

        private static string GetXmlCommentsPath()
        {
            return System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\bin\CalendarDetails.XML";
        }
    }
}
```

Will you please let me know where am I going wrong?

Comment: Define what you mean by "correct output". The Swagger endpoint is not authenticated. The API key being provided is to ensure that when you use the swagger ui to "test" a call to the API it is documenting, that the API key is passed. 
So if that is still giving you the correct output, then your actual API is not actually checking the API key.

Comment: By 'correct output', I meant the same output which I was getting with correct API key. My expectation was that if I give any API key other than the correct API key, then it should give error. Shouldn't it?

Comment: Sorry. I need to be more explicit: If you are using the swagger ui to exercise an api endpoint, and you have provided swagger with the incorrect api-key, then it is the API being exercised, not swagger, that is behaving improperly.

Comment: What version of Swashbuckle are you using?